# How to add a line in sed if not match is found

Tags: bash, sed

I am using the following `sed` command to replace some parameters in a config file:

```
sed -i 's/^option.*/option=value/g' /etc/fdm_monitor.conf
```

Now I have one problem. If the line does not exist, I want to add it to the bottom of the file.

I am calling this with a `popen` out of a C program. I tried using `awk`.